# Como capturar informação da linha de comando

Tags: c++

Como fazer para que, ao digitar um caracter, eu possa ler o próximo sem que o loop continue até finalizar a contagem de iterações? Segue código abaixo.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int aluno;
    float a,b,c,d,p;

for(int n=1; n<=5000; n++){

    cout<<"Digite o nome do aluno"<<endl;
    cin>>aluno;
    cout<<"Digite a nota do primeiro bimestre"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Digite a nota do segundo bimestre"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Digite a nota do terceiro bimestre"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"Digite a nota do quarto bimestre"<<endl;
    cin>>d;

    p=(a+b+c+d)/3;

    if(p>=6){
        cout<<"O aluno "<<aluno<<" foi aprovado, a media dele corresponde a  "<<p<<endl;
    }

    else{
        cout<<"O aluno "<<aluno<<" foi reprovado, a media dele corresponde a "<<p<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"..........................................................."<<endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas coisas:

- `for(int n=1; n<=5000; n++)` isso será repetido 5000 vezes. Acho que é muita repetição para ficar entrando dados pelo teclado até terminar
- Você declarou aluno como inteiro (`int aluno;`). O correto seria declará-lo como uma string, ou seja, mude a declaração para `std::string aluno;`

Comment: Obrigado irmão!!!!
Me ajudou muito!
Muito obrigado!